# How to call constructor function inside new object in its own class

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

When I try to call `this.logger.error()` inside `new Promise` it won't work.How can I call `this.logger.error()` inside the `new Promise`. As of my knowledge `this` refers to the outside class, how to call the `logger` inside `Promise` object.

```
export class MyClass {
    constructor(@Inject(WINSTON_MODULE_PROVIDER) private readonly logger: Logger) {}


    async uploadfile(buffer, key: string): Promise<string> {
            const params = {
                Body: buffer,
                Bucket: 's3Bucket',
                Key: key,
                ContentType: 'application/pdf',
                ACL: 'public-read',
            };
            const path: string = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        this.logger.error('Error',err)
                        reject('Error occurred');
                    }
                    return resolve(data.Location);
                });
            });

            return path;

    }
}
```

Comment: change `function(err, data)` to `(err, data) =>` - that way, that function will also have the `this` you want - => functions don't have "their own this" ... or something ... anyway, do that

Comment: @Bravo sorry I didn't see that until i refresh By the way your suggestion worked, Thank you

Answer (score -1):

The keyword `this` will only bind the scope which it is called. Calling it directly in a function that is not a class member/instance will bind to the function scope.
You can assign `this` to a variable and use the variable inside your Promise

```
class Example {

instanceFunction(){
  const thisReference = this
  return new Promise((accept)=>{
  accept(thisReference)
})

}
```

Above is example of how you would do it

Comment: You know how arrow functions work ... right?